# thymeleaf layout dialect TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.DecoratorProcessor'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

## background

I am using `spring web 4.3.4`, `thymeleaf 2.1.5`, `layout dialect 1.4.0`. I use `xml` configuration instead of Java configuration.

my context configuration is as follow :

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
    <property name="templateEngineMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

it works fine when i do not use any layout features, including `@{...}` for loading static assets, replacing fragments using `th:replace`. but when i try to run the sample from [here](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/blob/1.4.0/README.md#examples) using `layout:decorator`, it does not work

my file structure :

- WEB-INF

  - assets

    - js
    - css
  - views

    - Content1.html
    - Layout.html

I find that there might some issues on `layout:decorator` due to [this](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/issues/112). therefore i tried the following cases but no luck.

- `layout:decorator="Layout"`
- `layout:decorator="/Layout"`
- `layout:decorator="~{Layout}"`
- `layout:decorator="~{/Layout}"`
- `layout:decorator="'Layout'"`
- `layout:decorator="'/Layout'"`
- `layout:decorator="'~{Layout}'"`
- `layout:decorator="'~{/Layout}'"`

## questions

- does my context xml set correctly ?
- does my `layout:decorator` set correctly ?
- if not, what should be the correct case ?

thanks for helping. any help is appreciated